# Retrieving GetExecutingRequests from PowerShell into c# object

Tags: c#, powershell

I am trying to retrieve data from PowerShell into a c# object. The data I am looking for is returned from a PowerShell Invoke() of GetExecutingRequests on a remote web server. The issue I'm having is that I am not getting an error code, but the results from the Invoke() that I'm looking for are nowhere in the return data, or on the PowerShell object.

```
using (Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(cxn))
            {
                runspace.Open();
                using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
                {
                    ps.Runspace = runspace;

                    string script = String.Format("Get-WmiObject 
    WorkerProcess -Namespace root\\WebAdministration -ComputerName {0} | 
    Invoke-WmiMethod -Name GetExecutingRequests", server);

                    ps.AddScript(script);
                    ps.AddParameter("OutputElement", new HttpRequest[0]);

                    var result = ps.Invoke();
                }
            }
```

This code executes, and returns a Collection with 29 items. However, none of them show the GetExecutingRequests results, and there is nothing relevant on the PowerShell object either.

I would like to get the output of GetExecutingRequests into a c# object, so I can do further processing. the PSDataStreams on the ps object also have no results.

Any help would be appreciated.

MORE INFO:

I was able to solve this with a change to the PowerShell script I was sending:

`string script = String.Format("Get-WmiObject WorkerProcess -Namespace root\\WebAdministration -ComputerName {0} | Invoke-WmiMethod -Name GetExecutingRequests | %{{ $_ | Select-Object -ExpandProperty OutputElement }}", server);`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure if I can resolve the results directly, but I'd advise running below command to get some some more information on the object being returned. From there, you could look into how you'd handle that returning in C#.

```
Get-WmiObject -Class $(<scriptblock>) | get-member
```

1. Define the object types in C# & see if you're able to capture it in that way first.

If you're not able to make any progress with capturing the object type being returned in powershell yourself, it may be worth posting here to see if anyone else might be able to offer any insight/experience with workarounds for interfacing those objects types into C#.

2. If above really isn't possible, forcing the powershell to return everything from standard out would help find if it's writing anything meaningful that you can scrape/format in C#. I think the best way to do that in your quoted powershell command would be like so:

   return $(Get-WmiObject 
   WorkerProcess -Namespace root\WebAdministration -ComputerName {0} | 
   Invoke-WmiMethod -Name GetExecutingRequests | *>&1)

This returns all 5+ standard outs from powershell to the return object (for those reading, see [these docs on ps streams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-6)). Youshould definitely be able to capture the return in your results variable, but it can't hurt to make sure you're able to throw/capture errors from overflow.

Hope this helps to continue the digging!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was able to solve it, but it was similar to your suggestion. +1